# Looping over rasters in list with QGIS script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler, qgis-2.14

Using QGIS 2.14, I want to loop over rasters in a list with a QGIS script.

```
##Input_raster1=raster
##Input_raster=raster
##resul_rasters= output raster
list=[]
list.append(Input_raster1)
list.append(Input_raster2)
for file in list:
  processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', file,[],'ifelse(gt(a,-1),1,0)',False,7,result_raster)
```

This script just return one result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of specifying individual `raster` parameters, you can use the `multiple raster` which allows you to select **any number of loaded rasters** (these are described further in the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#creating-scripts-and-running-them-from-the-toolbox)). That way, you don't need to create a list. I've modified your script slightly and changed the `output raster` to `folder` so that you can specify where you want the rasters to be saved, the output names will also be the same as the input name:

```
##Input_raster=multiple raster
##result_rasters=folder

import os

layers = Input_raster.split(';')
for raster in layers:
    result_name = os.path.basename(raster)
    processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', raster, [], 'ifelse(gt(a,-1),1,0)', False, 7, result_rasters + "/" + result_name)
```

Comment: @Dokpe - Most welcome =)